# IP based link unreachable only from my VPS IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, whitelist

I have my own windows VPS with IP address 182.XXX.XX.XXX, i have ip based link http://182.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/EnterpriseUi/pushAction/OTM%3D.html?username=asd&password=asd&from=asd&to=91XXXXXXXXXX&text=hi

My problem is, when I am remotely connecting to my server, open any browser and run URL mentioned above it is showing me error message

"This site can’t be reached, 182.XXX.XXX.XX took too long to respond."

When I am accessing same URL from any browser of any other machine, it is working as expected.

I checked with my VPS provider they told me they don't have put any restriction on ip 182.XXX.XXX.XX.

Can any on help me to find out what is the issue.

Comment: Please clarify. you are saying that only your computer cannot connect, but everyone else can connect.
In that instance its probably an issue with your computer, not the server?

Comment: @Davef it is happening only on my server, i am able to access link from any other machine,and if there can be issue with my computer, then what it can be ?

Comment: The first octet of the address should not be removed from the question. With it removed, it is no longer possible to tell whether or not the machine is numbered inside RFC1918 space, which changes the question significantly. I would give a completely different answer to the edited question than I would have to the original question. I fixed this by restoring the first octet of the address.

Answer (score 0):

> took too long to respond

That basically means that the `TTL` died, so the communication failed.

How is it possible from other machines?

Well, if this happens on the same network it'd be weird but could be because of the network card not working as it should but, if you can only access from other networks, that might mean that your network is just too slow that makes the packets die in the meanwhile.

Anyways, this is quite strange, so make sure that you are not blocked by them.

Answer (score 0):

It can be lot's of things.

1- Somewhere in the path to the server with IP 182.156.191.54 the connection is lost

2- The server with IP 182.156.191.54 is rejecting your connection for some reason

3- Your server do not allow connections to/from the IP 182.156.191.54 (check your firewall)

I tried myself and cannot connect to this link from a VPS in Brazil. I used the traceroute tool (tracert in windows) and I can see that the connection was droped after the hop with IP 115.113.247.6 (http://prntscr.com/ax6cn8), so I belive that the problem is with the site you're trying to access. Maybe there is some kind of country/IP based block or the site is offline.

I'd suggest you to contact the owner of the site you're trying to access and teel your problem, it's your best chance to fix it.

Comment: MY server has no restriction to IP 182.xxx.xxx.xx

Comment: by the way i did same thing you explain above, yes connection is dropped after hop with 115.113.247.6